# Access - Object variable or with block not set

Tags: email, ms-access, outlook, vba

I have a Issue System where user can open tickets and input their comments in it. The tables are SQL linked tables.

I am trying to implement auto fetch contents of emails by adding a Button.

Basically, it will goes to a particular folder "Pendings" in Outlook and get all the emails which are not marked as "Copied".

Here is the code.

```vb
Public Sub myinbox()
Dim TempRst As DAO.Recordset
Dim Olapp As Outlook.Application
Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim InboxItems As Outlook.Items
Dim Mailobject As Object
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim Olfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder


'MsgBox "It will take some time. So, Hang On!"

Set db = CurrentDb

Set Olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Inbox = Olapp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetFolderFromID("000000001A447390AA6611CD9BC800AA002FC45A03003683A021347CC54C82688B880BB383EC000000B95F710000") ' working folder ID

'
Set InboxItems = Inbox.Items
Set TempRst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("working") ' Table

For Each Mailobject In InboxItems
    'If Mailobject.UnRead Then
    If Mailobject.Categories <> "Copied" Then

    With TempRst

        .AddNew

        !Title = Mailobject.Subject
       ' !From = Mailobject.SenderName
       ' !To = Mailobject.To
       ' !Body = Mailobject.Body
        !OpenedDate = Mailobject.ReceivedTime
        '!email = Mailobject.SenderEmailAddress
        !OpenedBy = "Group1"
        !Priority = "(2) Normal"
        !Status = "Pending"
        .Update
        Mailobject.Categories = "Copied"
        Mailobject.Save
        Mailobject.UnRead = False


    End With

End If
Next

Set Olapp = Nothing
Set Inbox = Nothing
Set InboxItems = Nothing
Set Mailobject = Nothing
Set TempRst = Nothing

MsgBox "Emails updated successfully"

End Sub
```

The above code is working fine with the Local tables (which i tested Locally without linking to SQL). But, when I am trying to run the same code with the Linked SQL tables. I am getting this error:

> **Error : "Object variable or with block not set"**

at this line:

```
Set TempRst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("working")
```

Comment: If "working" is an existing table in your database, I have trouble imagining how this line could throw this error. Since you assigned a db variable, you should use `Set TempRst = db.OpenRecordset("working")` but that probably won't make a difference.

Comment: P.S. Is this the actual code, that reproduces the problem? See [mcve]

Comment: @Andre Thank you so much for your reply. 
Working is the Table in the database. I have dummy database in my local (not linked tables) and the above code works fine. But, the error is throwing when I run the same code on SQL Linked Tables.

I have "Set TempRst = db.OpenRecordset("working"), still getting the same error.

Comment: @Andre
Correctoin, the folder is "Pendings" not working. I edited my question. :)

Comment: Check if `Set TempRst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM working", dbOpenDynaset)` still produce the error

Comment: @LostReality Still same error. Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Set TempRst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM working WHERE <yourPkField> IS NULL", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

You need to use dbSeeChanges with SQL Server linked tables. Since you are only adding records, there is no need to select any existing records. Hence, the where clause.

Comment: still it throws the same error. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Please post your actual code and indicate the exact line of the error.

Comment: i have already posted the actual code and mentioned the exact line of the error in my Original Post. Thank you for taking time to look into this.

Comment: Your original code is posted. I see no reason for what I posted, to not work as I have written thousands of processes similarly. Please post your current code.